# Show frequency table with network size per group and per language in R

Tags: r, frequency-analysis

I have a dataset which is a csv file which had columns containing group,language. I previously wanted to 
-show the frequency table with network size per group and per Language and I achieved this as follows:

```
ftable( #frequency wraper
    xtabs( ~ network
           + group
           + language
           , data=edge_list)
)
```

I now want to find the frequency table with network size per group of French Language. How would I go about achieving this?
Thanks in advance for help as I am new to R.

Comment: please provide a reproducible example. As it is we can't test your code.

Comment: You need to say what mean by "frequency table". Is this the proportions with values between 0 and 1? I would have thought you had what you were asking for. Need the data format. Post `dput(head(edge_list))`